# Is there a way to sync my todo list with my desktop & iPhone/iPod touch?

Tags: sync, iphone, lightning

I currently use Thunderbird/Lightning for my calendar. It syncs great with Google Calendar which syncs with my iPod touch. Now I want the same kind of process for a task list.

I like remember the milk, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do a two-way sync on Lightning/Sunbird. I have used the plugin for sunbird, but its kind of buggy and doesn't work with the nightly of it which I use because I find it to be more stable then the latest stable release.

I know about the remember the milk desktop applications, but I am looking for just one application to do everything.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you, I wanted something smooth and quick which ran on both my iPhone and my Computer. The solution I found, was [Google Tasks](http://mail.google.com/tasks). The problem with this, however, is that it requires internet to be present, so you would need an iPhone with working 3G/GPRS when you need to add something on the go!

It has a complete iPhone interface!

Whenever you need it on your computer in a simple interface, I suggest using the [mobile version](http://mail.google.com/tasks/ig) here as well.

Comment: There also looks to be a solution for offline tasks with that: http://www.geetasks.com/

Answer (score 0):

One option if you don't mind a mostly desktop-based todo list, I would suggest looking into Things.  Beautiful interface, easy syncing between desktop and i(phone|pod) and it syncs with iCal.  It may be able to be tweaked to fit into lighting/sunbird.  This is of course dependent on you using a mac as your computer.  Otherwise, just ignore this whole post.